# Why did so many Swedish raised in other Scandinavia countries vote for Sweden Democrats?

Tags: election, sweden

According to [the result on the recent election in Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_general_election,_2018), the largest support for the Sweden Democrats party comes from the cohort *Raised in Scandinavia outside of Sweden*, at 36%. This is higher than the other cohorts that are often said to support the party (i.e. [low-income, less-educated blue-collar men in rural](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1013963/Sweden-election-2018-who-vote-for-Sweden-Democrats-eurosceptic-party-Sweden-news)), including the following (average is 18%):

- Unemployed: 24%
- Permanently outside the labor market: 30%
- Blue-collar workers: 24%
- Less than nine years of school: 35%
- Compulsory comprehensive school: 27%

But I have never seen any comments regarding the voting tendency of the foreign-born citizens. Is it simply the small sample problems (but in that case they should put N/A or have no reason to show the result by foreign-born) or is there any reason why they have such large support for the party? The linked page does not show the number of samples on each category.

Comment: You need to clarify the question : According to Wikipedia this cohort is Foreign born  raised in Scandinavia outside of Sweden, not just raised in Scandinavia outside of Sweden  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_general_election,_2018#Voter_demographics